# Many to many associations with sequelize, node and express in the front-end

Tags: express, get, frontend, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between categories and words. Each word has exactly one category. **How can I write a get method with express and sequelize that takes all words and the belonging category from the junction table?** The returned json value should just contain the word and category but right now I'm getting the whole word object with and empty array for the categories…

I'm building a project for school where I have to make an full stack application. We can choose our own technologies.
I've choosen React, Node.js, Express and Sequelize with MySQL.

This application is a game that simulates the "wheel of fortune". We have a administration panel and the game itself. Currently I'm working on the admin-panel where an admin is able to make all kinds of CRUD operations for the game elements.

In the UI is a list shown that displays as example these words and the belonging category. So I'm stuck there.

We have words and questions with three possible answers. Every word and question has exactly one category. **I think we need a many to many relationship between the words and categories aswell for the questions and categories**.

CAN ANYONE HELP ME?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Include to get the desired result, given that correct relationships are defined in the sequelize model. e.g

```
const logs = await Junction.findAll({
  where: { categoryId: req.params.id },
  include: ['Words','Category'],
});
```

This will give you all the Words in juction table with Word and Category object,

Comment: Wouldn't „categoryId: req.params.id“ mean that I display all words for a specifique category? I need all existing words and the category next to it (without id).

Comment: just remove the where clause.